# Do we always have tensor diagram notation for all tensor operations?

Tags: tensors

Sorry for possibly naive question. For the context, I read the following tensor operation like $Q_{kl}=\sum_{j=1}^d R_{klj} F_{kj}$ in paper ([Fourier Neural Operator for Parametric Partial Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.08895.pdf)) page 5 equation 5. I understand the operation and can compute this with python tensor contraction packages with $Q = contract('klj, kj->kl', R, F)$.

I'm not expert in tensors, and have not encountered such operation before. I was familiar with $Q_{l}=\sum_{j,k} R_{klj} F_{kj}$, which can be expressed in Einstein summation $Q_{l} = R_{klj}F_{kj}$. Here repeating index usually get summed. But how can $Q_{kl}=\sum_{j=1}^d R_{klj} F_{kj}$ be expressed in Einstein summation? and also I was reading about [tensor diagram notation](https://tensornetwork.org/diagrams/). I cannot figure out how to represent $Q_{kl}=\sum_{j=1}^d R_{klj} F_{kj}$ in a tensor diagram.

Comment: Please add work you've done, things you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this operation cannot be expressed in Einstein notation. Einstein understood very well that the contraction only makes sense if it performed between a covariant and a contravariant factor, so each index in Einstein notation of a contraction can only appear exactly two times - either in a contraction, once as an upper index and once as a lower, or once in one of the arguments and once in the result.

But there is a difference in how tensor contraction is understood in (most of) mathematics and in computing. This is because in computing we usually fix the basis beforehand and not bother with change of bases and the fact that all operations must be equivariant. Because of this, most computational libraries do not distinguish between upper and lower indices, and allow the same index to appear more than two times. There are two ways to think about these operations with more than two indices.

If an index `k` appears, like in your example, in all arguments and in the result, it is often makes sense to think of the arguments not as tensors, but as collections of tensors indexed by `k`. In your example  the three-way array $R_{klj}$ represents a collection of matrices $R_{1lj}, R_{2lj}, \dots$, and the two-way array $F_{kj}$ — a collection of vectors $F_{1j}, F_{2j}, \dots$ The operation expressed as `klj, kj -> kl` is a *batched matrix-vector multiplication* — we multiply each matrix by the corresponding vector and collect the resulting vectors again into a two-way array indexed by $kl$.

The simplest operation of this kind is the coordinate-wise product of vectors (also known as Hadamard product). It corresponds to the expression `k,k->k` and here we interpret the arguments not as vectors, but as arrays of scalars, and multiply the corresponding ones.

The other way is to use the diagonal tensor $I_{ijk} = \begin{cases} 1, &\text{if $i = j = k$,} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and write the "contraction" $R_{klj}\, F_{kl}$ as $R_{\bar{k}lj}\, F_{\bar{\bar{k}}l}\, I_{\bar{k}\bar{\bar{k}}k}$. This now has only usual contractions involving two indices, and in the tensor diagram you can use the tensor $I$ (I have seen it denoted by a shaded triangle or a dot with three outputs).